# How to change SAS time values into date time values?

Tags: datetime, sas

Currently I have the timestamp column in **time format** with values such as :

*1041592
1040583
1048448*

and when I am  applying the datetime18. format on this column I am getting the following values

*27OCT78:16:21:21
15SEP78:16:21:21
09AUG79:08:58:39*

Could you please help me where I am going wrong , I want it to be displayed in date and time format , CURRENTLY iam getting the above values.

Comment: Exactly how to you want the values displayed?

Comment: I want it to be displayed date and timestamp but the year is displayed as 78 not sure why 27OCT78:16:21:21 want this format but with right year

Answer (score 0):

You need show your work.  I don't get what you say you get.

```
122  data _null_;
123     input dt @@;
124     put 'NOTE: ' (3*dt) (=best. =datetime. =time12.);
125     cards;

NOTE: dt=1041592 dt=13JAN60:01:19:52 dt=289:19:52
NOTE: dt=1040583 dt=13JAN60:01:03:03 dt=289:03:03
NOTE: dt=1048448 dt=13JAN60:03:14:08 dt=291:14:08
```